# 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, smtp

```html
I've searched through a bunch of other posts about how to fix the STARTTLS error but everything I've tried doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help??? development.rb:
<br> require 'starttls'
<br> config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
<br> enable_starttls_auto: true,
<br> address: "smtp.gmail.com",
<br> port: 587,
<br> domain: "gmail.com",
<br> authentication: :plain,
<br> user_name: "myusername without the '@' and domain",
<br> password: "mypassword"
<br> }
<br> config.consider_all_requests_local = true
<br> config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'localhost:3000' }
<br> #Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
<br> config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors= true 
Inside of my devise.rb:
<br> config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'
<br> config.parent_mailer = 'ActionMailer::Base'
```

I've enabled access through apps on my gmail account (which I doubt is the problem). Some of the code like ActionMailer is there because I got that from some older posts. I have the enable_starttls_auto
    to true but it still returns me the error. The main action I'm trying to do is the password reset/recovery.
    
 My version of ruby: `ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]`
    
 My version of rails: `Rails 5.1.5`
    
 My version of devise:
    
 name: devise
    
 version: !ruby/object:Gem::Version
    
 version: 4.4.3
    
 platform: ruby

Comment: Sorry if the coding is weird or whatever, this is my first time actually posting on stackoverflow. Thank you for reading this though!